# How to load a "|" delimited file into hive without creating a hive table with "ROW FORMAT DELIMITER"

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am trying to load a local file with "|" delimited values into hive table, we usually create a table with option "ROW FORMAT DELIMITER "|" . But I want to create a normal table and load data . What is the right syntax I need to use, please suggest.

Working Code

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  testdb.TEST_DATA_TABLE
(  column1                string,
column 2        bigint,
)ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|';
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH 'xxxxx.csv' INTO TABLE testdb.TEST_DATA_TABLE;
```

But I want to do :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  testdb.TEST_DATA_TABLE
(  column1                string,
column 2        bigint,
);
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH 'xxxxx.csv' INTO TABLE testdb.TEST_DATA_TABLE FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|';
```

Reason begin: If i create a table, HDFS will store the data in the table with "|" delimeter

Comment: ` If i create a table, HDFS will store the data in the table with "|" delimete` why is this a issue ?

Answer (score 0):

With second DDL you have provided, `Hive will create default formatted table like Textformat,orc,parquet..etc(as per your configuration)` with `cntrl+A` delimited file(default delimiter in hive).

If you want to store the `hdfs file` with pipe delimited then we need to `create Hive Table in Text with | delimiter`.

**(or)**

You can also write the result of select query to [`local (or) HDFS`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-Writingdataintothefilesystemfromqueries) path with pipe delimiter also.

Comment: Hello, I understand but I am looking for how to load a local pipe delimited file into default hive table ?.

Comment: From hive docs: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-Loadingfilesintotables `Hive doesn't supports specifying `Fields terminated by `while Loading files into tables`. we still needs to `create hive table with the specific delimiter` matches with the `file delimiter` that we are loading..!